# How do I make menu link go back to index page and slide to specific height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this long `index.html` that has links to external pages, so my question is how to link them from those external pages back to `index.html` to specific height with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".scroll").click(function(event){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '+= whatever px'}, 800);
});
});
```

To be more specific, I need files `1klopa.html` and `2trattoria.html` from `.zip` to link to `index.html` with implemented menu bar to specific height with above code or similar...
So if someone needs whole website to understand the code it's quite long and in zip here, virus free and free to review:
    https://mega.co.nz/#!8lRRlSga!_R5RzEN1ZhGcyQcohOiGzjnEYYmlgN8_ANsvQ4WGNUE

I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add some anchors in your index.html:

`<a name = "scrollTarget1"></a>`

Create links from external sites to the anchor:

`<a href = "index.html#scrollTarget1">Link to anchor</a>`

The browser will take care of scrolling your site to the desired position and it will even work without any JavaScript invocation.

Comment: i'm sorry i am noob in this coding..as i understand, i basically need to add to menu links in 1klopa.html and 2trattoria.html <a href="index.html#anchor></a> with #anchor as css and in index.html at places i need link to go to i need to add <a name="anchors"></a>  ?
what do i put in css in that case?
sry for bothering you..

Comment: @user3799813 There is no need to apply any css for making anchors work. Just put the `<a name = "..."></a>` as close as possible to the content that should be visible in browser window on link click. Everything else will be done by the browser itself.